# adverbs order in a sentence

Tags: adverb-placement

> 1.Body movement takes place during sleep just before the REM stage.
>
> 2.Body movement takes place just before the REM stage during sleep.

When there are two phrases of  ''time adverbs'' in a sentence, which phrase should be written first?

I prefer #1 as ''sleep'' will do first and "REM'' stage comes later.

Answer (score 1):

They are equally grammatical, however, from the point of view of the presentation of information, the first is stylistically superior, in my opinion, since it introduces the more general idea "body movement during sleep" and after that the more specific "just before the REM stage". The focus is narrowed.

In the second, the focus is (perhaps unnecessarily) broadened from "just before the REM stage" to "during sleep". For those readers who may be unfamiliar with "REM stage", better to offer information that gives its context before the reader reaches the term than to reorient the reader afterwards.